# How to properly compile bootstrap documentation and open locally?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I downloaded the [Bootstrap v5](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/) source, and compiled the docs with `npm run docs` as advertised. I can see that the process compiles the docs and saves them to:

```
./bootstrap-5.0.0-alpha1/_gh_pages/docs/5.0/...
```

This directory contains a couple of `index.html` files in subdirectories. However, if I open one of them, they all contain a redirection to `https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction` so I can't open my local files.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/">
```

I would like to use the Bootstrap documentation system for my own documentation, does anyone know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

First download the [v5.0.0-alpha1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v5.0.0-alpha1.zip) source.

```
cd bootstrap-5.0.0-alpha1/

npm install
```

You can then run the documentation locally via:

```
npm run docs-serve
```

If everything goes smoothly, you should see something like the following.

> Web Server is available at http://localhost:9001/

The documentation serves when you browse that local URL from localhost. To locate the docs on your computer, they are stored in `/bootstrap-5.0.0-alpha1/site/content/docs/5.0` as markdown files.